# How to use a field in ROW type column in Flink SQL?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I'm executing a SQL in Flink looks like this:

```
    create table team_config_source (
      `payload` ROW(
        `before` ROW(
          team_config_id int,
          ...
        ),
        `after` ROW(
          team_config_id int,
          ...
        )
      ),
      PRIMARY KEY (`payload`.`after`.`team_config_id`) NOT ENFORCED
    ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'xxx',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'xxx',
    'properties.group.id' = 'xxx',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
    'format' = 'json',
    'key.format' = 'json'
    )
```

But Flink give me this error:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "." at line 51, column 29.
Was expecting one of:
     ")" ...
     "," ...
```

I've also tried to replace `` (`payload`.`after`.`team_config_id`) `` with `` (`payload.after.team_config_id`) ``, but Flink will say that `column payload.after.team_config_id was not defined`.

How should I correct my DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skip this problem by dropping the `PRIMARY KEY` sentence.